# Kohsuke or Kosuke?

Tags: names, rōmaji

I saw a person write his name in Romaji as Ko**h**suke. I am a beginner Japanese student and it struck me as odd to see that "h" in there. I would have thought his name to be written as Kosuke if it were to follow proper form.

Is the introduction of the single "h" a common convention to aid with pronunciation? Or perhaps something he just does to set his name apart from others?

Unfortunately I do not have access to the Kanji representation of his name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kosuke is not bad, but one may think of it as こすけ rather than his actual name こうすけ.

I think it is common to use "h" to avoid this. For example, famous baseball player [王]{おう}[貞治]{さだはる} played with "OH" on his back.

An alternative way to handle this kind of pronunciation is to use a macron like Kōsuke.